# How are BarButtonItems added to the NavigationBar?

Tags: ios, navbar

I was handed an application to improve upon. As it stands currently, it has a left bar button and a right. I was reading that it's possible to add more than just two items, though (please, correct me if I'm wrong! If I'm right, feel free to add input!). So I'm working on that right now. The problem is that I've searched through the code and I cannot find where these buttons are being added to the NavigationBar! It's as if it happened magically!

Is there a different way to add buttons to the NavigationBar without actually writing the code for it? I don't understand how these are being added.

Comment: Is the app using a storyboard (a file with the .storyboard suffix)?

Answer (score 2):

```
UIBarButtonItem * trash = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemTrash
                                                                        target:nil
                                                                        action:nil];

UIBarButtonItem * action = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction
                                                                         target:nil
                                                                         action:nil];

[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItems:@[trash, action]];
```

Results in...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, the buttons are added in the Storyboard file / xib file of the view controller.

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep in mind iOS standards so you can see in the developer site for  "iOS Human Interface Guidelines" to be sure that you desing strategy is valid, if you need many options use a UITabBarController (its the standard) or use a  Segmented Control

in the documentation [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/Bars.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH12-SW4) you find some tips like this **"Avoid crowding a navigation bar with additional controls, even if it looks like there’s enough space"**

Sometimes you can add aditional buttons but be careful how many you use.

Cheers